# What does "satisfactory definition" mean?

Tags: turing-machines, artificial-intelligence, turing-test

I am reading the book Artificial Intelligence (A modern approach) by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig. While reading the book, I saw the below sentence in the book.

> The Turing Test, proposed by Alan Turing (1950), was designed to provide a satisfactory operational definition of intelligence.

Now the question is, what does the writer mean by saying ***satisfactory definition***?
Does it have a special mathematical meaning (like as we say in some problems: *f(x) satisfies some conditions*)? or does the *satisfactory* adjective just mean *good enough* (as stated in Longman dictionary)?

Comment: It’s a nontechnical term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means nothing in particular.  You can read it as "good enough".  It is not encoding some specific technical meaning.